# String not saving on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this code snippet where I'm trying to add favorites so they can get saved.
I see they are getting added since the icon is toggling, however when I reload the app the favourites disappear.

How could I get the favourites to actually "save"?

Edit: Wrong phrasing

Code Snippet:

```
    class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    @Published var favs: Set<String>
    
    private let saveKey = "favorites"
    
    init() {
        //load saved data
        
        self.favs = []
    }
    
    func contains(_ name: String) -> Bool {
        favs.contains(name)
    }
    
    func add(_ name: String) {
        favs.insert(name)
        objectWillChange.send()
//        save()
    }
    func remove(_ name: String) {
        favs.remove(name)
        objectWillChange.send()
//        save()
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to show your view code. My suspicion is that you're creating multiple `Favorites` objects. By the way, because you're using `@Published`, you don't need to use `objectWillChange.send()` -- that will happen automatically.

Comment: If you are looking for persistent storage, have a look at UserDefaults or CoreData. If this is what you want, have a look at the `@AppStorage` wrapper.